# MVC project No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, interface, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

im getting this error. Im newbie on MVC .
Can you help me please.I found somethings but i didnt understand what i will do. Sorry for my english. 
I have 4 projects in a solution
.Admin 
.UI
.Core
.Data
I have a problem with admin side.
Im trying to LoginFilter in admin page. When i run the project the page forwarding to /Account/Login page but its giving this error.

Error Page:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +206
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'WebHaber.Admin.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +194
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1098.0
```

AccountController.cs

```
using WebHaber.Core.Infrastructure;
using WebHaber.Data.Model;

namespace WebHaber.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        #region Kullanıcı
        private readonly IKullaniciRepository _kullaniciRepository;
        public AccountController(IKullaniciRepository kullaniciRepository)
        {
            _kullaniciRepository = kullaniciRepository;
        }
        #endregion

        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Kullanici kullanici)
        {
            var KullaniciVarmi = _kullaniciRepository.GetMany(x => x.Email == kullanici.Email && x.Sifre == kullanici.Sifre && x.Aktif == true).SingleOrDefault();
            if (KullaniciVarmi != null)
            {
                if (KullaniciVarmi.Rol.RolAdi == "Admin")
                {
                    Session["KullaniciEmail"] = KullaniciVarmi.Email;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                ViewBag.Mesaj = "Yetkisiz Kullanıcı";
                return View();
            }
            ViewBag.Mesaj = "Kullanıcı Bulunamadı";
            return View();
        }
```

LoginFilter.cs

```
namespace WebHaber.Admin.CustomFilter
{
      public class LoginFilter : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
        {

            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
            {
                HttpContextWrapper wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                var SessionControl = context.HttpContext.Session["KullaniciEmail"];
                if (SessionControl == null)
                {
                    context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary { { "Controller", "Account" }, { "action", "Login" } });

                }

            }

            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {}
```

BootStrapper.cs

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;
using WebHaber.Core.Infrastructure;
using WebHaber.Core.Repository;
using WebHaber.Data.DataContext;

namespace WebHaber.Admin.Class
{
    public class BootStrapper
        {
            //Boot aşamasında çalışacak.
            public static void RunConfig()
            {
                BuilAutoFac();
            }

            private static void BuilAutoFac()
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

                builder.RegisterType<HaberRepository>().As<IHaberRepository>();

                builder.RegisterType<ResimRepository>().As<IResimRepository>();

                builder.RegisterType<KullaniciRepository>().As<IKullaniciRepository>();

                builder.RegisterType<RolRepository>().As<IRolRepository>();

                builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

                var container = builder.Build();
                DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

            }
        }
```

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BootStrapper.RunConfig();

        }
    }
```

KullaniciRepository.cs

```
namespace WebHaber.Core.Repository
{
   public class KullaniciRepository : IKullaniciRepository
    {
        private readonly HaberContext _context = new HaberContext();

        public IEnumerable<Kullanici> GetAll()
        {
            //Tüm haberler dönecek
            return _context.Kullanici.Select(x => x);
        }

        public Kullanici GetByID(int id)
        {
            return _context.Kullanici.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }

        public Kullanici Get(Expression<Func<Kullanici, bool>> expression)
        {
            return _context.Kullanici.FirstOrDefault(expression);
        }

        public IQueryable<Kullanici> GetMany(Expression<Func<Kullanici, bool>> expression)
        {
            return _context.Kullanici.Where(expression);
        }

        public void Insert(Kullanici obj)
        {
            _context.Kullanici.Add(obj);
        }


        public void Update(Kullanici obj)
        {
            _context.Kullanici.AddOrUpdate();
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var kullanici = GetByID(id);
            if (kullanici!= null)
            {
                _context.Kullanici.Remove(kullanici);
            }

        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return _context.Kullanici.Count();
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

IKullaniciRepository.cs

```
namespace WebHaber.Core.Infrastructure
{
    public interface IKullaniciRepository : IRepository<Kullanici>
    {
    }
}
```

IRepository.cs

```
namespace WebHaber.Core.Infrastructure
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

        T GetByID(int id);

        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);

        IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);

        void Insert(T obj);

        void Update(T obj);

        void Delete(int id);

        int Count();

        void Save();

    }
```

}

Kullanici.cs model

```
namespace WebHaber.Data.Model
{
    [Table("Kullanici")]
    public class Kullanici
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ad Soyad")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "150 karakterden fazla girildi.")]
        [Required]
        public string AdSoyad { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string KullaniciAdi { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Şifre")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required]
        public string Sifre { get; set; }
..............
..............
.............
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is pretty straightforward — `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'WebHaber.Admin.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

You're trying to use Autofac to inject `IKullaniciRepository` service into the `AccountController` but the compiler couldn't find one although you've the declared the service registration at `BootStrapper.cs`

Therefore it's likely that `BootStrapper.cs`'s `RunConfig` never get invoked. Just place a call (e.g. `BootStrapper.RunConfig()`) to `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax` and you're fine.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add my global.asax. Its already defined there.       
   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BootStrapper.RunConfig();

        }
    }
}

Comment: Have you any idea ?

Comment: Are you able to get other injected services in other place (e.g. HaberRepository)? Can you add the code excerpt for KullaniciRepository.cs & IKullaniciRepository.cs too?

Comment: It was first injected. Then i getting error im trying to find solution.

Comment: Hmm may I know what do you mean "first injected"? I wonder if it's due to the inheritance of multiple interfaces and whether you'll need to register the relationship between IKullaniciRepository & IRepository<Kullanici>.. Sorry as I'm not an expert in Autofac IoC, you can tag the question with autofac and hope to get more attention for solution.

Comment: I added some tags to my question . I wish someone help me ;) so my problem looking for about injection?

Comment: Yes you're right. The implementation of Autofac + Repository pattern is kinda new to me. Can you add the following right after the line "DependencyResolver.SetResolver" and step through it via debugger and check whether it's null?
var obj = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IKullaniciRepository>(‌​);

Comment: If i add project (i mean upload somewhere), can you check it.

Comment: I tried to put breakpoint so my global.asax file not running. Application_Start() method not firing . thank you for help. I need to find this problem now :)

Answer (score 0):

**@Zephyr** thank you for help.
I added new global.asax file.
Because my Application_Start() was not firing.

In global.asax
Old one :

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

new one: `

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication`
```